# Post multiple files in a single request using Active Collab API:

Tags: rest, api, activecollab

I'm using a self hosted Active Collab 5 setup and am trying to upload multiple files via `/upload-files`. I am sending a multipart form POST with each part name named `attachment_1`, `attachment_2` and so on.

Unfortunately only the first file in my request named `attachment_1` is being used and returns the file code response.

What is the correct way to upload multiple files through the API (without the SDK - our application is using Ruby ond Rails) at once?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Active Collab 5 does not accept multiple file uploads in a single request. To upload multiple files, please make multiple requests.

Keys that Active Collab checks are `file` or `attachment_1`.

Comment: thanks for the response. OK, we already built our interface that way. You should consider updating your API documentation then, because https://developers.activecollab.com/api-documentation/v1/projects/elements/files/files.html states: `There is also a way to upload a batch of files. First, lets upload them:`

Comment: Nearly five years later, I've run into this issue with our integration. The documentation is sorely in need of updating if multiple file uploads in a single request are not possible.